# Set whole cell background color using kableExtra

Tags: r, shiny, kableextra

I am creating a dashboard for dispatching trucks at my company. I created a table in `Shiny` that shows which trucks should be dispatched from which dock and certain times. The cell background is dependent on the trucks being on time or not. The issue is that using `cell_spec(background = ...)` from `kableExtra` is only coloring directly behind the text instead of filling in the full cell

I created 4 tables for company name, cell background, text color, text strikeout, which I merge into one using cell_spec. then that is split into two tables for morning and afternoon

```
    for(i in 1:nrow(df.live))
    {
        df.live[i, ] <- cell_spec(dt.live.output[i, ], 
                                  "html", 
                                  background = df.live.output.colors[i, ],
                                  color = df.live.output.colors.text[i, ],
                                  strikeout = df.live.output.colors.strike[i, ])
    }

    n.half <- round(ncol(df.live[i, ])/2,0)
    n.color.col1 <- ifelse(n.colored.column > n.half, n.half, n.colored.column)
    n.color.col2 <- ifelse(n.colored.column > n.half, (n.colored.column - n.half) + 1, 1)
    
    df.live1 <- df.live[, 1:(n.half)] %>%
        kable(format = "html", escape = F) %>%
        kable_styling(font_size = 18) %>% 
        column_spec(n.color.col1:n.half,
                    background = color.future) %>% 
        column_spec(1:n.color.col1,
                    background = color.past) %>% 
        column_spec(1, bold = T,
                    background = color.moolenaar,
                    width = "1em")
    
    
    df.live2 <- df.live[, c(1, (n.half+1):ncol(df.live))] %>%
        kable(format = "html", escape = F) %>%
        kable_styling(font_size = 18) %>% 
        column_spec(1, bold = T) %>% 
        row_spec(1:nrow(df.live), background = color.table.background) %>% 
        column_spec(1:n.color.col2,
                    background = color.past) %>% 
        column_spec((n.color.col2+1):n.half,
                    background = color.future) %>% 
        column_spec(1, bold = T,
                    background = color.moolenaar,
                    width = "1em")
```

I would like the background to fill the full cell instead of just the part directly under the text. I know this is possible with `format = "latex"` but is it somehow possible with `format = "html"`?