# How to fill entire cell of a table with cell_spec() in kabeleExtra?

Tags: r, kableextra

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56219601/set-whole-cell-background-color-using-kableextra) posed a while ago, does anyone know how I can fill the entire background of a cell using the `cell_spec()` function in `kableExtra`?

I have some dummy data below, but I can only manage to colour the background of the text. I'd prefer the entire cell filled and I'm pretty set on using `kableExtra` to create my table within an R Markdown file. Does anyone know of a workaround for this? Thanks.

```
library(kableExtra)

name <- paste("Name", LETTERS)
val <- rnorm(26, 100, 50)
d <- data.frame(name, val)

d$val <- cell_spec(d$val, background = if_else(d$val > mean(d$val) + sd(d$val),
                                              "#DBEBF6",
                                              if_else(d$val < mean(d$val) - sd(d$val),
                                                      "#FEE7DA",
                                                      "transparent")))

kbl(d, escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `cell_spec` only targets the cell content, i.e. the `span`  tag which contains the content, but not the parent table cell, i.e. the `td` tag. And by default some padding of `8px` is added to the content of the table cell.

One option to fill the entire cell would be to use the `extra_css=` argument of `cell_spec`, i.e. set the margin to `-8px` and the padding to `8px` so that the cell content fills the entire height of the cell. Additionally set `display: flex` to fill the entire width of the cell.

```
library(kableExtra)

set.seed(123)

name <- paste("Name", LETTERS)
val <- rnorm(26, 100, 50)
d <- data.frame(name, val)

d$val <- cell_spec(d$val,
  background = dplyr::case_when(
    d$val > mean(d$val) + sd(d$val) ~ "#DBEBF6",
    d$val < mean(d$val) - sd(d$val) ~ "#FEE7DA",
    .default = "transparent"
  ),
  extra_css = "margin: -8px; padding: 8px; display: flex;"
)

kbl(d, escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

[image]

**EDIT** With `display: flex` we need some additional CSS to center align the values (see e.g. [Aligning items in a flex container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Aligning_items_in_a_flex_container)):

```
d$val <- cell_spec(d$val,
  background = dplyr::case_when(
    d$val > mean(d$val) + sd(d$val) ~ "#DBEBF6",
    d$val < mean(d$val) - sd(d$val) ~ "#FEE7DA",
    .default = "transparent"
  ),
  extra_css = paste(
    "margin: -8px; padding: 8px;",
    "display: flex; align-items: center;",
    "justify-content: center;",
    sep = "; "
  )
)

kbl(d,
  align = c("l", "c"),
  escape = FALSE
) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @stefan. This works well. I'm wondering whether there is a way to keep the cell content/text of `val` centered. When I implement the `extra_css = ` argument in `cell_spec()`, the rendered text is aligned left even with `kbl(d, align = c("l", "c"))`. Do you have any additional suggestions to ensure the `val` column remains centered? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ben. See my edit. Because of `display: flex` we need some additional CSS.

Comment: Thank you, @stefan! This works perfectly and is exactly what I needed!